# Obtener valor que regresa una petición AJAX

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, login

Buenas tardes, tengo el siguiente escenario. Este mi `login.html`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title></title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="estilos/estilos.css"/>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>

<body>

   <div id="popup">
     <div id="formulario">
 <h1 id="header" align="center">Ingresar</h1> 
 <br>
 <hr>     
 <br>     
 <form action="Controlador/login.php" method="post" id="formlogin">
  <table>
      <tr>
       <td>Usuario:</td>
       <td><input type="text" name="usuario" id="usuario"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
       <td>Password:</td>
       <td><input type="password" name="password" id="pass"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
       <td>&nbsp;</td>
       <td><input id="botonl" type="submit"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
                 <td colspan="2" align="right"><a id="botonRegistrarse">¡Registrate!</a></td>
      </tr>
      </table>
     </form>
    </div>
   </div>
   <script src="js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script> <!--Utilizar libreria JQUERY-->
   <script src="js/codigo.js"></script> <!--TODO lo que utilize JQUERY deberá ser referenciado           despues de la libreria.-->
</body>
</html>
```

Este manda las variables usuario y password a `Controlador/login.php` que es donde, enviadas las 2 variables se procesan para comprobar el ingreso exitoso del usuario.

```html
<?php
 require_once('../Modelo/class.conexion.php');
 require_once('../Modelo/class.consultas.php');

 $usuario = $_POST['usuario'];
 $pass = $_POST['password'];

 if(strlen($usuario) > 0 && strlen($pass) > 0){
  $consultas = new Consultas();
  $mensaje = $consultas->verificarUsuario($usuario, $pass);
   if (is_string($mensaje)) {
    echo $mensaje;
   }else{   
    session_start();
    foreach ($mensaje as $resultado) {
         $user = $resultado['nickname'];
         $rango = $resultado['rango'];
    }
     $_SESSION['usuario'] = $user;
                 $_SESSION['rango'] = $rango;

                if ($_SESSION['rango']=='Administrador'){
                                         echo "Administrador";
     //echo "header('Location: ../manga.html');"; 
    }elseif ($_SESSION['rango']=='starter') {
     header("Location: ../login.html");
    }elseif ($_SESSION['rango']=='Viper') {
     header("Location: ../index.html");
    }
   }   
  }else{
  echo "Por favor rellena ambos campos";
 }  
?>
```

El método `verificarUsuario` , es el siguiente:

```html
public function verificarUsuario($nombre_usuario,$password_usuario){
 $modelo = new Conexion();
     $conexion = $modelo->get_conexion();
 $sql = "select nickname, password, idUsuario, rango
   from usuarios
   where nickname = :nombre_usuario 
   and password = :password_usuario";
 $statement = $conexion->prepare($sql);    
 $statement->bindParam(':nombre_usuario', $nombre_usuario);
 $statement->bindParam(':password_usuario', $password_usuario);
 if(!$statement){
  return "Error verifique parametros";
 }else{
  $statement->execute();
  if($statement->rowCount() > 0){       
   return $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
  }else{
   return "no hay usuarios con registrados con esos datos";
  } 
 }  
   }
```

Hasta ahí todo bien, ahora como mi `login.html` tiene esa referencia a mi archivo `JS` donde con `JQuery` y `Ajax` intento hacer que dependiendo del rango de usuario logueado lo mande a una pagina u otra.

Teniendo el siguiente fragmento de código `JS`

```js
$('#botonl').click(function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  usuario = $('#usuario').val();
  password = $('#pass').val();

  $.ajax({
   url: 'Controlador/login.php',
   type: 'POST',
   data: {usuario, password},
   beforeSend:function(){
    console.log("Se esta procesando tu peticion");
   }
  })
  .done(function(data) {
   console.log("success");
                         alert(data);
   if (data == 'Administrador') {
    document.location.href = "manga.html";
    alert(data);
   }
   else{
    alert("ERROR POR QUE TE ODIO");
   }
   }
  })
  .fail(function() {
   console.log("error");
  })
  .always(function() {
   console.log("complete");
  });
 });
```

El código no funciona correctamente, por ejemplo, si ingreso como un usuario Administrador, me manda el `alert` con el mensaje "Administrador" mas sin embargo en el `if` entra al `else` y me manda el `alert` "ERROR PORQUE TE ODIO", por lo tanto no me redirige hacia donde se tiene establecido, y con los otros casos, en el `alert` me trae todo el código `html` de dichas páginas.

Cualquier ayuda u observación será bien recibida, muchas gracias.

Comment: Estaba escribiendo una respuesta, pero veo cosas muy raras en `login.php`. ¿Usas ese archivo **para otras cosas** o es un simple verificador  para llamar desde jQuery/Ajax en este caso? Pregunto porque viéndolo de cerca parece que lo usas también para que los usuarios se logueen y quieres usarlo también para **esta** petición-verificación vía Ajx. Para la petición Ajax es recomendable usar un archivo php que sólo sea usado para eso.

Comment: ¿Qué ves de raro?, Pues desde el `html` envió las 2 variables que recibe `login.php` este las procesa para verificar el acceso.

Comment: Una de las cosas que veo raras es esta:  `session_start();
    foreach ($mensaje as $resultado) {
         $user = $resultado['nickname'];
         $rango = $resultado['rango'];
    }
     $_SESSION['usuario'] = $user;
                 $_SESSION['rango'] = $rango;` no entiendo por qué usas `$_SESSION` ahí...

Comment: Ah okey, pues es que como ahí mismo se loguea el usuario, utilizo sesiones para que si recargas la página, ya este el usuario logueado sin necesidad de volver a loguearse, y el `foreach`, es para recorrer el arreglo que me regresa el metodo `verificarUsuario`

Comment: No es correcto entonces usar `login.php` para enviar tu petición Ajax en este caso. Tienes que crear un archivo php dedicado específicamente para hacer las verificaciones que necesitas desde tu código jQuery.

Comment: En el data: {usuario, password}, debes ponerlo como data: {'usuario': usuario, password: 'password'} , te falta las claves o los nombres de las propiedades del json pasado en el POST

Comment: Gracias por tu comentario, lo solucioné mandando un json_encode en la respuesta a la petición ajax y luego con jquery lo recorrí y establecí condiciones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Por si a alguien le sirve puede tomar esto como apoyo.

Mi codigo `HTML`.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title></title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="estilos/estilos.css"/>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>

<body>
<div id="popup">
  <div id="formulario">
   <h1 id="header" align="center">Ingresar</h1> 
   <br>
   <hr>     
   <br>     
   <form action="Controlador/login.php" method="POST" id="formLogin">
    <table>
    <tr>
     <td>Usuario:</td>
     <td><input type="text" name="usuario" id="usuario"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>Password:</td>
     <td><input type="password" name="password" id="pass"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>&nbsp;</td>
     <td><input id="botonIngresar" type="submit"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td colspan="2" align="right"><a id="linkRegistrarse">¡Registrate!</a></td>
    </tr>
    </table>
   </form>
  </div>
 </div>
 <script src="js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script> <!--Utilizar libreria JQUERY-->
 <script type="js/jquery.validate.min.js"></script><!--Lo utilizamos para validar campos-->
 <script src="js/codigologin.js"></script> <!--TODO lo que utilize JQUERY deberá ser referenciado           despues de la libreria.-->
</body>
</html>
```

El código `PHP`: Aquí lo que hice mejor, fue que dependiendo de la condición que se cumpliera, esta regresará en la petición `AJAX` un `json_encode` generado en este archivo `PHP`.

```html
<?php
 require_once('../Modelo/class.conexion.php');
 require_once('../Modelo/class.consultas.php');

 $usuario = $_POST['usuario'];
 $pass = $_POST['password'];

 if(strlen($usuario) > 0 && strlen($pass) > 0){
  $consultas = new Consultas();
  $mensaje = $consultas->verificarUsuario($usuario, $pass);
   if (empty($mensaje)) {
    //echo ("No hay usuario registrados con esos datos");
    $error = ['No existen usuarios registrados con esos datos'];

    $arrayJson = json_encode($error);
    print_r($arrayJson);
   }else{   
    foreach ($mensaje as $resultado) {
         $user = $resultado['nickname'];
         $id = $resultado['idUsuario'];
      $pass = $resultado['password'];
        $rango = $resultado['rango'];
        $estadoCuenta = $resultado['estadoCuenta'];
    }

    if ($estadoCuenta == 'ban') {
     $error = ['Usted no tiene acceso al sistema, contacte a la administración'];

     $arrayJson = json_encode($error, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
     print_r($arrayJson);
    }else{
     session_start();

     $_SESSION['idUsuario'] = $id;
      $_SESSION['usuario'] = $user;
          $_SESSION['password'] = $pass; 
          $_SESSION['rango'] = $rango;

          $arrayJson = json_encode($mensaje);
     print_r($arrayJson);
    }
  }
 }else{
  //echo "Por favor rellena ambos campos";
  $error = ['Por favor rellena ambos campos'];

  $arrayJson = json_encode($error);
  print_r($arrayJson);
 }  
?>
```

Y este es el código de mi archivo `JS`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 //EFECTUAR INGRESO AL SISTEMA MEDIANTE PETICION AJAX
 $('#botonIngresar').click(function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  usuario = $('#usuario').val();
  password = $('#pass').val();
  var rangoUsuario;

  $.ajax({
   url: 'Controlador/login.php',
   type: 'POST',
   dataType: 'JSON',
   data: {usuario, password},
   beforeSend:function(){
    console.log("Se esta procesando tu peticion");
   }
  })
  .done(function(data) {
   console.log("success");
     $.each(data, function(index, val) {
      if (val.estadoCuenta == 'ok') {
       if (val.rango == 'Administrador') {
        document.location.href = "admin.php"
       }else if(val.rango == 'Viper' || val.rango == 'starter'){
        document.location.href = "index.php"
       }else if(val == 'No existen usuarios registrados con esos datos'){
        alert(val);
       }else if(val == 'Por favor rellena ambos campos'){
        alert(val);
       }
      }else{
       alert(val);
      }
     });
  })
  .fail(function() {
   console.log("error");
  })
  .always(function() {
   console.log("complete");
  },'json');
 });
});
```

Espero que le sea de utilidad a alguien más. Saludos.

Answer (score 1):

Vale tendrías que hacer la prueba pero creo que solo esta mal tu `$.ajax`
al enviar tu **data** porque este debería de enviar un objeto `json` y tu no estas haciendo eso:

Entonces lo que esta mal es:

> data: {var1, var2},

Este debería ser

`data: {var1:var1, var2:var2},`

Esto solo porque tu obtienes los datos en `login.php` de esta forma:

```
$usuario = $_POST['var1'];
$pass = $_POST['var2'];
```

Lo conveniente es tener todo en orden y con su nombre como debería de ser, para que otros desarrolladores puedan entender tu código.

Podrias cambiar el **data** de tu `ajax` por:

`data: {usuario:var1, password:var2},`

Y Obtenerlos en `login.php` asi:

```
$usuario = $_POST['usuario'];
$pass = $_POST['password'];
```

Espero que esto resuelva tu problema.

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta, antes de postear la pregunta tuve en cuenta eso que me comentas, mas sin embargo el error persiste, cuando hago la petición ajax esta si me regresa en el `alert` el rango del usuario que ingreso, pero luego en el `if` en mi codigo `javascript` entra en el `else` y me despliega el mensaje de `ERROR PORQUE TE ODIO`