# Problemas con "IF"

Tags: javascript

resulta que estoy trabajando con javascript y me ha tocado hacer esto.

```
let ejemplo = "si";

if (ejemplo == "si") {
    //realiza 'x'
} else {
    //realiza 'y'
}
```

Hasta ahí todo bien, si mi variable `ejemplo` tiene el valor "si" solo realiza 'x' y si tiene un valor diferente de "si" realiza 'y'.

Pero cuando hago este cambio ya no sucede igual

```
let ejemplo = "si";

if (ejemplo != "si") {
    //realiza 'x'
} else {
    //realiza 'y'
}
```

Cualquier valor que le doy a `ejemplo` solo me realiza 'x', en teoría si le doy "si", debería realizar 'y', pero no sucede eso.

Alguna idea?

Comment: Proba cambiando != por !==

Comment: El código debería funcionar. ¿Dónde estas ejecutando el script?

Comment: Acabo de probar ese codigo y funciona ok <script>
 let ejemplo = "esto es una prueba";

 if (ejemplo != "esto es otra prueba") {
     console.log("SI - SOY DISTINTO A LA VARIABLE")
 } else {
     console.log("NO - SOY IGUAL A LA VARIABLE")
 }
</script>

Comment: @LcsGrz voy a probarlo y te comento.

Comment: @MatiasOlivera, si te refieres al HTML, el script lo estoy ejecutando al final, antes de la etiqueta de cierre </body>.

Comment: @Juan primera vez que me ocurre eso, no sé a que se puede deber

Comment: Eso no debería estar pasando. Tienes más código, o solo es ese?

Comment: Verifica como te llega el dato tal vez te llega con un espacio al final y vos lo estas comparando con uno que no tiene ese espacio

Comment: Si el valor de `ejemplo` viene de otro sitio, conviene que la limpies con `trim`, haciendo algo así: `let ejemplo = "si".trim();` [Ver aquí para más detalles](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/103952/29967) Sería como hacer:  `let ejemplo = ReferenciaoElemento.trim();` Haciendo eso, si los datos te vienen así: `si `  o así `si\n`, quedarán limpios de espacios o saltos de línea sobrantes.

Answer (score 0):

El problema podria estar en como los lenguajes de programación usan los 'Strings', para comprara strings se recomiendan métodos de los mismos lenguajes o frameworks de terceros.
En este caso podrias resolverlo utilizando esto

```
string_a.localeCompare(string_b);
```

La funcion devolvera

> 0:  son iguales
>
> -1:  string_a < string_b
>
> 1:  string_a > string_b

Y tu funcion quedaria:

```
let ejemplo = "si";

if (ejemplo.localeCompare("si") !== 0) {
    //realiza 'x'
} else {
    //realiza 'y'
}
```