# ¿Por que no entra en el condicional?

Tags: javascript

Tengo este código. Despues de ejecutarse el ajax compruebo que se han insertado correctamente los datos y en la consola veo "inserted". Pero por alguna razón que desconozco el código dentro del condicional no se ejecuta. ¿Alguien sabe a que se debe?

Muchas gracias de antemano.

````
   $.ajax({
        url: './libs/php/queue_song.php',
        method: 'POST',
        dataType: 'text',
        data: {
            songTitle: songTitle
        },
        success: function(response) {
            console.log(response)
            if (response == "inserted") {
                console.log("Song inserted successfully")
            } else if (response == "error") {
                console.log("Error")
            }
        }
    })```
````

Comment: El console a `response` ¿qué respuesta trae?

Comment: por la consola veo "inserted"

Comment: Limpia `response` con `trim()` ya que a veces los datos del servidor vienen con un salto de línea como he explicado en [esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/103952/29967).

Comment: Para limpiar la respuesta puedes hacer algo así: **`var s=response.trim(); if (s == "inserted") { console.log("Song inserted successfully");  } else if (s == "error") { console.log("Error"); }`** Para más claridad he guardado la respuesta limpia en una variable `s` la cual se usa luego en los `if`

Comment: Bingo! Se me ha quitado hasta el dolor de cabeza!! XD Gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Es porque tu respuesta no sigue buenas prácticas.

Cuando trabajas con un API, generalmente se utiliza JSON. Seguramente tu endpoint `/libs/php/queue_song.php` devuelve una respuesta tipo `plain/text` en cuyo cuerpo se encuentra la cadena "inserted", por eso se ve en la consola pero es incapaz de comprobar si `response == "inserted"`.

Por buena práctica, tu endpoint `/libs/php/queue_song.php` debe devolver un JSON tipo: `{"response": "inserted"}`.

Verifica, por una parte, que tu que tu endpoint devuelva un `content-type: application/json`, por otra, que el objeto tenga como key algo que consultes en tu AJAX:

```javascript
success: function(response) {
  response // {"response": "inserted"}
  response.response // "inserted"
  response.response == "inserted" // true
  // ...
}
```

Puedes seguir esta documentación para ver cómo devolver un JSON con PHP:
https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_php.asp

Comment: Sería mejor citar documentación oficial: https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.json-encode.php

Comment: Gracías. No sabía que usar el formato texto eran malas practicas. El problema se arregló con la solución del response.trim() pero ya que me comentas todo esto lo cambiaré por formato json para evitar futuros dolores de cabeza.